# How do I equip the Hestia Knife or other gear I receive from quests?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

I just obtained the Hestia Knife from Story 5-7.

How can I equip the knife?

I found that it is located in my special inventory...
[image: Hestia Knife in Special Inventory]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Hestia Knife, along with other items that you receive from quests, must be exchanged before they can be equipped. Below I have steps for the Hestia Knife but they are universal and can be applied to all quest equpment.

By following these steps you can exchange the Special Item for the weapon:

1. From the home screen choose Shop,
2. Choose "Special Exchange" the last option.
3. Choose Equipment Exchange

   [image: Special Exchange]
4. Select the Hestia Knife.

   [image: Exchange]
5. Confirm your exchange

   [image: Reward from exchange]
6. Return to the home screen
7. Choose Party
8. Select Bell by pushing and holding on his picture.
9. Choose equipment.
10. Select the Hestia Knife.

    [image: Hestia Knife Selected in equip screen]
11. Select Equip

    [image: Equipped]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This has got to be the most convoluted equipment process I have ever seen...